# Entity Framework 6 - Attaching a graph of entities queried with AsNoTracking

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I am retrieving a list of entities from a table `FattureFornitori`, and loading also a collection owned by them (Voci, plural form - Voce, singular form) and a reference from each `Voce` to a `TipoCosto` entity:

```
var db = new DbGestPre();
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
var s = db.FattureFornitori
            .Include(x => x.Voci)
            .Include(x => x.Voci.Select(y => y.TipoCosto))
            .AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Now, multiple `Voci` within a single `FattureFornitori` can reference the same `TipoCosto`.
So, when I try to attach a single `FattureFornitori` with its Voci and the referenced `TipoCosto`, I face the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Attaching an entity of type 'GP.Model.TipoCosto' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.'
```

Some debugging for that one FattureFornitori entity, here named ff, reveals:

```
ff.Voci[1].IdTipoCosto == ff.Voci[0].IdTipoCosto
true
ff.Voci[1].TipoCosto == ff.Voci[0].TipoCosto
false
```

So Entity Framework creates multiple instances for the same entity! So the error raised by the attach method makes sense.
But how to solve this situation??
I looked after GraphDiff and other tools like those but they cannot help.
Any hint?
Thanks!!

Comment: Remove `AsNoTracking()`. Then EF will create unique `TipoCosto` instances.

Comment: But I don't want EF to keep track of these entities, nor that it creates proxies. I need to perform the most lightweight operation possible.

Comment: It's just that removing `AsNoTracking` makes life much easier. It doesn't require proxy creation, by the way. If it doesn't affect performance too much I'd go for it.

Answer (score 1):

As Gert Arnold suggests, one workaround is to remove AsNoTracking().
But this means that the DB context will add ALL the entities to the tracked entities, so it will perform badly.

I tried the following code:

```
var db = new DbGestPre();
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
var s = db.FattureFornitori
                .Include(x => x.Fornitore)
                .Include(x => x.Voci)
                .Include(x => x.Voci.Select(y => y.TipoCosto));
List<FatturaFornitore> data = s.ToList();
db.Dispose();
```

To quickly detach the entities from the context, I Disposed the context. Any faster/better approaches are welcome.
This code ran in 858ms.

My former alternative

```
var db = new DbGestPre();
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
var s = db.FattureFornitori
                .Include(x => x.Fornitore)
                .Include(x => x.Voci)
                .Include(x => x.Voci.Select(y => y.TipoCosto))
                .AsNoTracking();
List<FatturaFornitore> data = s.ToList();
```

ran in just 500 ms.

So I am still looking for a way to make this version of the code with AsNoTracking working.

Comment: Big chance that any deduplication code you'd need because of `AsNoTracking` will take more than 358 ms. I think the alternative with `AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false` is the best you can get.

Comment: @GertArnold can you please elaborate more? I don't get you

Comment: Well, the code with `AsNoTracking` needs a deduplication step afterwards, doesn't it? (* Entity Framework creates multiple instances for the same entity!*). I wonder if that can be done in 858-500=385 ms.

Comment: oh ok now I have understood! :) Yes, sure.